# when I change the table data how the date will change automatically in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the table. The table has 10 rows and 4 columns(i.e: Sl.No., Project Name, ChangeDate, Changed By).When I modify in project name, in corresponding changeDate column how the date will automatically changed to today date using php?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Project</title>
    <script>
        function GetCellValues()
        {
            var str = '';
            var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            var table=document.getElementById("project");
            for (var i=0;i<table.rows[0].cells.length;i++)
            {
                if (i > 2 )
                {
                    str = str + table.rows[0].cells[3].innerHTML.replace(", ");
                }
                else
                {
                    str = str + (table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML) + ', ' ;
                }
            }
        for (var c = 1 ; c < rows.length ; c++)
        {
            str += '\n' + "0" + c + ', ';
            var row = rows[c];
            var inputs = row.getElementsByTagName('input');                
            for (var k = 0 ; k < inputs.length ; k++)
            if (k > 1)
            {
                str += inputs[k].value.replace(", ");
            }
            else 
            {
                str += inputs[k].value + ', ';
            }
        }   
        document.getElementById('hide').value = str;
        //alert(document.getElementById('hide').value);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body background="floor.jpg">
    <form action = "" method = "POST">
        <br>
        <h1><center><u>PROJECT</u> :</center></h1>
        <br>
            <input type="hidden" id="hide" name="hide" value="">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick = "GetCellValues()" value = "SAVE" />            
        <br>
        <table id = "project"  border= "1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0"
    style = "border-color: brown; background-color:silver;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width:60%">
    <tr>
        <th align="center" width="10%" id = "Sl.No." >Sl.No.</th>
        <th align="center" width="30%" id = "Project Name" >Project Name</th>
        <th align="center" width="30%" id = "ChangeDate" >ChangeDate</th>
        <th align="center" width="30%" id = "Changed By" >Changed By</th>
    </tr>
    </table>        
    </form>
    <?php
        $handle = fopen("data.txt", "r+");
        $hide = $_REQUEST['hide'];
        fwrite($handle,$hide);
    ?>  
    <?php
        $file = file('data.txt');
        $lines = count($file);      
        $dtFormatted = date("m-d-Y");
        echo'<table id = "project"  border= "1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0"
            style = "border-color: brown; background-color:silver;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width:60%">';
        for ($i=1; $i<$lines; $i++) 
        {
            $part = explode(',', $file[$i]);
            echo'<tr>
                <td align= "center" width="10%">'.$part[0].'</td>
                <td align= "center" width="30%"><input type="text" placeholder="Text Box" value='.$part[1].'></td>
                <td align= "center" width="30%"><input type="text" value='.$dtFormatted.'></td>
                <td align= "center" width="30%"><input type="text" placeholder="Text Box" value='.$part[3].'></td>  
            </tr>';
        }
        echo'</table>'; 
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: how to change the date field automatically when I change the project name?@OlivierH

Comment: Again, `What have you tried so far ?`

Answer (score 0):

Define the change date field in mysql as

```
changeDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON  UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

With that definition, the change date field always contains the date and time of the last modification. Mysql will take care of it and you won't need to do it in PHP.